# Organize aged receivable report in alphabetical order

Tags: reporting, odoo-14, accounting

In odoo V12 or v14
when I generate my aged receivables report, it is not organized in alphabetical order. Is there any module or method available to organize this report alphabetically based on customers and vendors?
thanks

---